# html tag width not working in asp .net email

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am trying to send email from my code.

```
emailBody.Append("<p style=\"background-color: #ffff42;width: 200px;\"><strong>" + "Hello" + "</strong></p>");
```

In this tag, it highlights the background, but it does not restrict the highlighter to 200px, instead it highlights whole row. So width parameter is not working. I want to restrict the background highlighter only till Text ends.

Instead of style/background-color tag , I tried  tag, and it also didn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried the <mark> tag?

Comment: Yes, Mark tag does not highlight and simply prints the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"p" HTML tag is a block element, it will fill the entire row or the specified width, to limit the styling to only the content, apply the styling to an inline HTML tag encapsulating only the content, from your example, applying styling to "strong" should work, or wrap any desired content in a "span" tag.

```cs
emailBody.Append("<p style=\"width: 200px;\"><strong style=\"background-color: #ffff42;\">" + "Hello" + "</strong></p>");
```

Comment: Yes and it will fill the specified width with the background color, remove the styling from the "p" if you do not want the element be filled with it and apply the styling to the content only

Comment: can you write the code what you are saying, it's bit confusing

Comment: I tried that also by removing width, and it is still highlighting entire row in my email

Comment: sorry, I see that what you are saying now, let me check that